# how to get hours from subtracting two date time values in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have two date values: `08/6/2009 00:00:00` and `10/6/2009 23:59:59`.

How do I get the difference in hours in a query in SQL Server 2005?

Comment: your title is somewhat misleading. Are you asking how to calculate a timespan in hours using T-SQL for SQL Server 2005?

Comment: Hi, i don't fully understand you but if you wan to get difference as hours you can use DATEDIFF() to get difference and then get it as hours but getting days using DATEPART() and multipley th numbers of day by 24 to get it as hours
Best Regads,Iordan

Comment: Since it seems MS SQL Server does not support SQL standard INTERVAL types, nor any approximation to them, any solution I proposed based on those is of limited value.  Where standard intervals are supported, the answer is more or less trivial: CAST((d2 - d1) AS INTERVAL HOUR(9)).  You might need to pull some more casting stunts to get that to a plain number instead of an INTERVAL...in one system I use, that would mean cast to char, and then to INTEGER.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(hour, '2009-08-06 00:00:00', '2009-10-06 23:59:59')

---
 71
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DATEDIFF(HOUR,'08/6/2009 00:00:00','10/6/2009 23:59:59')
```